# Saas customization api

Tags: api, user-interface, customization, saas

we are creating a saas web service application and wanted to add customization which will allow tenants & users to add custom attributes to an existing entity Or (add custom entities and associate them with custom attributes).

Is it possible?

how should the web service and UI(consumer application) handle these custom attributes?  JSON & XML

what should be considered on DB for achieving the same goal?

Please explain technologies with which we can achieve this and drawbacks of using it for a enterprise level large tenant based application. Open for Java Or .Net Technologies and frameworks.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

what should be considered on DB for achieving the same goal?

If you looking for the implementation in java to implement the multi-tenant application.
You can a have a look into the Athena Framework.
http://athenasource.org/

For the customized UI framework ;/
Well Even I am looking for some UI solution which can be very customizable by the tenants.